# Set ClientID in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, client-side, asp.net-controls, clientid

Is it possible to set the `ClientID` of any asp.net server control? How can I do this?

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve and then we might be able to suggest an alternative.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The good news is that in VS 2010 .Net 4, you'll have [complete control over Client IDs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/26/starter-project-templates-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)!

Still for the current versions of .Net, you can make due.  I assume you need the ID for JavaScript.  If so, just get the ID like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myTextBox = $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>');
</script>
```

Comment: +1 for being a Jedi and reading ebattulga's mind, "Get ClientID I do not Set"

Comment: Don't forget to put the # sign in front of the <%= pending you want to get the actual DOM object and not just the text of the control's ClientID.

Comment: Thx @Kswift87 that's absolutely right. i've updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

I would advice against doing this unless you are sure you want to do it, but there is a way. You can override the `ClientID` property from within the server control.

```
public override string ClientID
{
    get { return "whatever"; }
}
```

But as others have noted, you can't do it from outside.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible. The ClientID is generated by ASP.NET. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx):

> The ClientID value is generated by
>   concatenating the  ID value of the
>   control and the  UniqueID value of its
>   parent control. If the  ID value of
>   the control is not specified, an
>   automatically generated value is used.

Answer (score 1):

Even i think it is not possible in Visual studio 2008 . Because [Control.ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) Property has only get method

Edit :But in Visual studio 2010(.Net 4.0) it is possible

Comment: How is it possible? In VS2015 this method is still only get.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 4 has ClientIDMode property on each control for that.
If you want to **turn off ClientID completely** you can use [this trick](http://clientidless.codeplex.com/) - it works for any non-postback control

Answer (score 0):

This is an ASP.NET 4.0 feature.

Answer (score 0):

For VS 2010, .NET 4.0:

If you just try to set `ctrl.ClientID="stringID"` you will get an Error, saying that ClientID is read only. You can control the value of ClientID using [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) - which defines the algorithm with which ClientID is set:

```
ctrl.ID = "IDstring";
ctrl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;   //ClientID value is set to the value of ID
```

The html markup will mark your control's html with the control's ID. Thus you have some degree of control from the code-behind.